# Beautiful Soup: extract all data between tags

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, tags

```
<p>
 <strong>
  <em>
   Insurtech
  </em>
 </strong>
</p>
<p> .....Some data </p>
<p>
 <strong>
  <em>
   Biometrics
  </em>
 </strong>
</p>
```

I tried this: 
    html_tags = soup.find_all('em')
    for i in range(len(html_tags)-1):
     start_tag = html_tags[i]
     end_tag = html_tags[i+1]
     between_tag = (soup_str.split(str(start_tag)))[1].split(str(end_tag))[0]
     soup1 = BeautifulSoup(between_tag, 'html.parser')
I want all the data from first `p->strong->em` to the next `p->strong->em` tag.This is my sample data.Thanks in advance**

Comment: Have you tried any methods to get it ? If yes, please include those here

Comment: I tried html_tags = soup.find_all('strong'), which gave list of data in the strong tag. But I want all the data. Output :[<strong><em>Insurtech</em></strong>, <strong><em>Biometrics</em></strong>]

Comment: What I really want is a list from [Insurtech ... to someData , Biometrics ... someData,  and so on]

Comment: Is this what you want? `['Insurtech', '.....Some data', 'Biometrics']` or only the text surrounded by `strong` tags?

Comment: ['Insurtech .....Some data'] as one item ['Biometrics  ... and following data'] as another item

Comment: Please add above code into the question, please !!!

Comment: Please format the code correclty

Answer (score 2):

```
s = '''<p>
 <strong>
  <em>
   Insurtech
  </em>
 </strong>
</p>
<p> .....Some data </p>
<p>
 <strong>
  <em>
   Biometrics
  </em>
 </strong>
</p>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

>>> list(soup.stripped_strings)
['Insurtech', '.....Some data', 'Biometrics']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.text` method to access the required info.

**Ex:**

```
s = """<p>
 <strong>
  <em>
   Insurtech
  </em>
 </strong>
</p>
<p> .....Some data </p>
<p>
 <strong>
  <em>
   Biometrics
  </em>
 </strong>
</p>"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(s, "html.parser")
html_tags = soup.find_all('p')
for h in html_tags:
    print(h.text.strip())     #-->Update.
```

**Output:**

```
Insurtech
.....Some data
Biometrics
```

Comment: But I also want the data between the two tags "Some data" in this case

Comment: @Meredith. In that case use `p` instead of `strong`. Updated snippet.