# Text extract from two consequent span tags with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to extract text values from two consequent span tags together.

```
<span class="research-details-footer-key">Bathrooms:</span>, <span>1</span>
```

Comment: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling

Comment: please include your attempts to code this/research.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
import re

pat = re.compile('>([\w:]*)<')
value = '<span class="research-details-footer-key">Bathrooms:</span>, <span>1</span>'

print(pat.findall(value))

output : ['Bathrooms:', '1']
```

Comment: You can also refer to links
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22247957/regex-to-find-words-between-two-tags

Comment: Could you please give an example in beautifulsoup? Thank you

Comment: please refer

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49668147/beautiful-soup-extract-all-data-between-tags

Comment: Sorry, since there is no class on second span, I cannot even get the second span. I need the both span together to combine both values.